# ¿Puedo especificar el parámetro jvmRoute del tomcat embebido en springboot a través del application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot

Necesito balancear desde un apache una app hecha con springboot.

He intentado con esta configuración, pero al autenticarse el usuario, parece que pierde la sesión:

```
<Proxy "balancer://micluster">
BalancerMember "https://maquina1.dominio.es:9543/app"
BalancerMember "https://maquina2.unirioja.es:9543/app"
</Proxy>

ProxyPass "/app" "balancer://micluster" stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse "/app" "balancer://micluster"
```

he visto ejemplos por ahí en los que ponen en cada miembro del balanceador la ruta al tomcat. Algo así:

```
 <Proxy "balancer://micluster">
 BalancerMember "https://maquina1.dominio.es:9543/app" route=jvroute1 
 BalancerMember "https://maquina2.unirioja.es:9543/app" route=jvroute2 
</Proxy>
```

Y esos valores, se deberían corresponder con el jvRoute de cada uno de los tomcats.
Es por probar esa opción porque no se me ocurre nada más.

Si se os ocurre otra alternativa, soy todo oídos!

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Cristina